# Incorrect array correction

Tags: java, arrays

So we were given a problem that goes along the lines of this:

> Write a program that mimics a mailman conducting an experiment in
>   flipping  mailboxes. A flip means opening a mailbox if it is closed,
>   and closing a mailbox  if it is open. There are 100 mailboxes numbered
>   1 to 100 that are all initially  closed.
>
> In the first step, visiting every mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 1, 2, 3,
>   ..., 100),  he flips them all. Then in the second step, visiting every
>   second mailbox  (i.e. mailboxes 2, 4, 6, ..., 100), he flips them.
>   Then in the third step,  visiting every third mailbox (i.e. mailboxes
>   3, 6, 9, ..., 99), he flips them.  In this manner he goes in steps of
>   4, 5, ..., 10,...,50, and finally 100,  wherein he directly goes to
>   the 100th mailbox and flips it. At the end of this  process, which
>   mailboxes are open?

So I went along and made a program utilizing a nested for-loop to do the flipping experiment:

```
    public class MailManProblem{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            boolean mailbox[] = new boolean[101];
            int i,j,k,l;

            for(i=1;i<101;i++){
                for(j=i;j<mailbox.length;j+=i){
                    mailbox[j]=!mailbox[j];
                }
            }

            System.out.print("\nOpen Mailboxes \n");
            for(k=1;k<mailbox.length;k++){
                if(mailbox[k]==true)
                    System.out.print(k + " " );
                else
                    continue;
            }
            System.out.print("\n\n");

        }
    }
```

I thought all was well because it did print out the correct output but my instructor told me I had used a "wrong array size". I don't quite understand what that means. I have no ways of contacting my instructor ATM so I was wondering if I could get some help into fixing this "wrong array size" mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your instructor intended you to use array indices from 0 to 99 instead of 1 to 100 (despite the wording of the initial question) and just thought you had an extra element in your array?

Answer (score 0):

You've created the array 101 elements in size, but you don't use element 0.

```
boolean mailbox[] = new boolean[101];
```

You should create it only 100 in size.

```
boolean mailbox[] = new boolean[100];
```

And then loop from element 0 (the first element) to 99 (the 100th).

```
for(i=0;i<mailbox.length;i++)
```

But then when you print the index, add one to it, to correct it back to the 1 to 100 range, which humans prefer, rather than the 0 relative indexes computers prefer.

```
System.out.print((k+1) + " " );
```

Don't forget to adjust that loop range also..

```
for(k=0;k<mailbox.length;k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of your array should be 100 instead of 101. Also, you'd need to change your `for` loops to start from 0 instead of 1. As a result, the condition would change to `i < 100`.

At the moment you are not utilising the first element of the array because you start the loop at `i = 1`.